# call the model of the secondary database in djnago using Multiple Databases

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-settings

I am following Django multiple databases.
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/)

**settings.py**

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'database_1',
        'USER': 'username_1',
        'PASSWORD': 'password_1',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 'xxxx',
    },
    'secondary' : {
        'NAME' : 'database_2',
        'ENGINE' : 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'HOST' : 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
        'PORT' : 'xxxx',
        'USER' : 'username_2',
        'PASSWORD' : 'password_2',
    },
}
```

As the documentation suggests we need to create a router.

```py
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['app_name.router.AuthRouter', ]
```

**routers.py**

```py
class AuthRouter:
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    auth and contenttypes applications.
    """
    route_app_labels = {'login','images'}

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read auth and contenttypes models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'database_2'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write auth and contenttypes models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'database_2'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Allow relations if a model in the auth or contenttypes apps is
        involved.
        """
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or
            obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
        ):
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Make sure the auth and contenttypes apps only appear in the
        'auth_db' database.
        """
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == 'database_2'
        return None
```

I need to access database_2 there are two apps in the Django project that. is ( login , Images )

Inside

```
-login (App)
--UserProfile ( Table_name)
```

Now there is no way for me to access `secondary database` and read this `UserProfile` Table.

Any suggestion can also be big help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you should return `secondary` in `AuthRouter` instead `database_2`.

Comment: I have updated that but still am not able to access tables of secondary?

Comment: But being able to access for the default database properly here is error am recieving. ```>>> login.objects.using('secondary').all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'login' is not defined ``` @Random1k11